# Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to fix the error "ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 602 but received input with shape [None, 370]" (more console output shown below)

I get this error after trying to create a neural network model from a connectivity matrix using my createModel function and then attempting to train the model using the handwritten digits MNIST database. Would anyone be able to help me resolve the outputted error? All relevant code is shown below. Any help/assistance is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

The error:

```
(base) [patelvrajn@VArchLinux Proof_of_Concept]$ python3 Posted/main.py
Generating chromosome         1 of         5
Finished generating chromosome         1
Generating chromosome         2 of         5
Finished generating chromosome         2
Generating chromosome         3 of         5
Finished generating chromosome         3
Generating chromosome         4 of         5
Finished generating chromosome         4
Generating chromosome         5 of         5
Finished generating chromosome         5
Finished generating all chromosomes.
Generating models

...

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 602 but received input with shape [None, 370]
```

The following code is what I have in main.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, concatenate, Lambda
from random import *
import numpy as np
import chromosome as c
from enum import Enum

EPOCH_OR_ERROR_PROBABILITY = 50
EPOCHS_MAXIMUM = 1000 
TRAINING_SET_MINIMUM = 100
LAYERS_MAXIMUM = 4
NEURONSPERLAYER_MAXIMUM = 4
INITIAL_POPULATION_SIZE = 5

class Model_Gen_State(Enum):
    inputlayer_state = 1
    hiddenlayer_state = 2
    outputlayer_state = 3

#Generates a random integer or float - works!
def randomNumber(minimum,maximum,isFloat):
    random = 0
    if isFloat:
        random = uniform(minimum, maximum)
    else:
        random = randint(minimum, maximum)
    return random

def createModel(connectivity_matrix,activation_list):
    #initialize initial/current state to input layer state
    current_state = Model_Gen_State.inputlayer_state

    #initialize variable for storing input layer
    input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(1,))

    #initialize list for skipped neurons & next layer skipped neurons
    skipped_neurons = []
    next_layer_skipped_neurons = []

    #loop through each array in the connectivity matrix
    for array_index in range(len(connectivity_matrix)):
        #change number of neurons at current layer according to index array
        layer_n_count = len(connectivity_matrix[array_index])

        #switch states
        if(array_index == len(connectivity_matrix) - 1):
            current_state = Model_Gen_State.outputlayer_state
        elif(array_index == 0):
            current_state = Model_Gen_State.inputlayer_state
        else:
            current_state = Model_Gen_State.hiddenlayer_state

        #initialize layer for processing according to current state
        layer = keras.Input(shape=(layer_n_count,))
        if(current_state == Model_Gen_State.inputlayer_state):
            input_layer = layer
        if(current_state == Model_Gen_State.hiddenlayer_state or current_state == Model_Gen_State.outputlayer_state):
            layer = next_layer

        #initialize counter for activation list
        al_index = 0

        #initialize list for storing groups
        groups_to_concat = []

        #reassign skipped_neurons for new layer and empty new layer skipped neurons
        skipped_neurons = next_layer_skipped_neurons
        next_layer_skipped_neurons = []

        #loop through column
        for col in range(len(connectivity_matrix[array_index][0])):            
            #initialize counter rows processed in this column
            processed_rows = 0

            #initialize list for storing segments  
            segments_to_concat = []

            #loop through all the rows in the column
            while(processed_rows < layer_n_count):
                #skip the neuron if it was in skipped neurons list 
                skip = False
                for skipped_neuron in skipped_neurons:
                    if(skipped_neuron == processed_rows):
                        skipped_neurons.remove(skipped_neuron)
                        skip = True
                if(skip):
                    processed_rows = processed_rows + 1
                    continue

                #the neuron's connectivity at fixed array (input only) and fixed col with varying row
                in_neuron = connectivity_matrix[array_index][processed_rows][col]

                #check if neuron's connectivity is 0 for this row
                if(in_neuron == 0):
                    processed_rows = processed_rows + 1
                    continue

                #start at a row where neuron connectivity is 1
                start_row = processed_rows

                #loop until you find the first 0 in the column with 0 neuron connectivity
                while(in_neuron == 1):
                    #increased the number of processed rows
                    processed_rows = processed_rows + 1
                    #do not let processed rows exceed the number of rows for this array
                    if(processed_rows >= layer_n_count):
                        processed_row = processed_rows - 1
                        break
                    #reassign the current neuron being processed
                    in_neuron = connectivity_matrix[array_index][processed_rows][col]

                #set end row to the last row where neuron connectivity was 1
                end_row = processed_rows

                #create the segment where output neurons had a connection to this neuron with consecutive 1s with the connectivity matrix
                input_segment = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,start_row:(end_row +1)])(layer)

                #add to segment list
                segments_to_concat.append(input_segment)

            #check length of segment list and set group according
            if(len(segments_to_concat) == 0):
                next_layer_skipped_neurons.append(col)
                continue
            group = segments_to_concat[0]
            if(len(segments_to_concat) >= 2):
                group = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(segments_to_concat)

            #make group of segments into a dense layer
            group = Dense(1, activation= activation_list[al_index])(group)

            #increase activation list index
            al_index = al_index + 1

            #add to group list
            groups_to_concat.append(group)

        #check group list length and set next layer according
        if(len(groups_to_concat) == 0):
            return
        next_layer = groups_to_concat[0]
        if(len(groups_to_concat) >= 2):
            next_layer = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(groups_to_concat)

        if(current_state == Model_Gen_State.outputlayer_state):
            return keras.Model(input_layer,next_layer)

        #empty the group list between layers
        groups_to_concat = []

        #assert to assure neurons in connectivity matrix and neurons generated are within range of each other
        assert(next_layer.shape[1] <= len(connectivity_matrix[array_index + 1])), "Layers mysteriously appeared at initialization of model."

def downloadMNIST(model, learning_rate, momentum, lr_decay):
    #MNIST Dataset
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
    x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
    y_train = y_train.astype('float32')
    y_test = y_test.astype('float32')
    x_val = x_train[-10000:]
    y_val = y_train[-10000:]
    x_train = x_train[:-10000]
    y_train = y_train[:-10000]
    model.compile(
            # Optimizer
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, decay=lr_decay, nesterov=True),
            # Loss function to minimize
            loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
            # List of metrics to monitor
            metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=128, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
    results = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
    predictions = model.predict(x_test[:3])
    return keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

def optimizerRandomSelection():
    optimizers = [keras.optimizers.Adadelta, keras.optimizers.Adagrad, keras.optimizers.Adam, 
                 keras.optimizers.Adamax, keras.optimizers.Ftrl, keras.optimizers.Nadam, 
                 keras.optimizers.RMSprop, keras.optimizers.SGD]
    return optimizers[randomNumber(0,len(optimizers)-1, False)]

def activationfunctionRandomSelection():
    activationfunctions = [keras.activations.elu, keras.activations.exponential, keras.activations.hard_sigmoid,
                          keras.activations.linear, keras.activations.relu, keras.activations.selu,
                          keras.activations.sigmoid, keras.activations.softmax, keras.activations.softplus,
                          keras.activations.softsign, keras.activations.tanh]
    return activationfunctions[randomNumber(0,len(activationfunctions) -1, False)]

def generateConnectivityMatrix(numofInputs, numberoflayers_maximum, numberofneurons_maximum):
    connectivitymatrix = []
    currentlayerneurons = numofInputs
    for index in range(numberoflayers_maximum - 1):
        nextlayerneurons = randomNumber(1, numberofneurons_maximum, False)
        layerconnectivity = np.zeros((currentlayerneurons,nextlayerneurons))
        for cn in range(currentlayerneurons):
            for nn in range(nextlayerneurons):
                layerconnectivity[cn][nn] = randomNumber(0, 1, False)
        currentlayerneurons = nextlayerneurons
        connectivitymatrix.append(layerconnectivity)
    return connectivitymatrix

def generateActivationList(numberofneurons):
    activationlist = []
    size = 0;
    while(size != numberofneurons):
        activationlist.append(activationfunctionRandomSelection())
        size = size + 1
    return activationlist

def main():
    #Initialization
    #Generate a list of random chromosomes
    chromosome_list = []
    for member_count in range(INITIAL_POPULATION_SIZE): 
        print("Generating chromosome % 9d of % 9d" %(member_count+1,INITIAL_POPULATION_SIZE))  
        cm = generateConnectivityMatrix(784, LAYERS_MAXIMUM, NEURONSPERLAYER_MAXIMUM)

        neuron_count = 0
        for cmarray_index in range(len(cm)):
            rows = len(cm[cmarray_index])
            cols = len(cm[cmarray_index][rows-1])
            if(cmarray_index == 0):
                neuron_count = neuron_count + (rows+cols)
            else:
                neuron_count = neuron_count + cols

        al = generateActivationList(neuron_count)

        o = optimizerRandomSelection()

        (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
        ts=randomNumber(TRAINING_SET_MINIMUM,len(x_train),False)

        ee = -1
        dice_roll = randomNumber(1,100,False)
        if(dice_roll >= EPOCH_OR_ERROR_PROBABILITY):
            ee = randomNumber(1, EPOCHS_MAXIMUM, False)

        cc = c.Chromosome(cm,al,o,ee,ts)
        chromosome_list.append(cc)
        print("Finished generating chromosome % 9d" %(member_count+1))

    print("Finished generating all chromosomes.")

    #From the list create a list of neural network models
    #Map the chromosome to their respective models
    for chromosome in chromosome_list:
        print("Generating models")
        chromosome.m = createModel(chromosome.cm, chromosome.al)
        downloadMNIST(chromosome.m, 0.01, 0.9, 1e-6)

    print("Complete")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The following code is what I have in chromosome.py:

```
import numpy as np

class Chromosome:

    def __init__(self, connectivity_matrix, activation_list, optimizer, epochs_or_error, training_set):
        self.cm = connectivity_matrix
        self.al = activation_list
        self.o = optimizer
        self.ee = epochs_or_error
        self.ts = training_set
        self.m = None
```

Comment: Could you please post the full traceback so that we can see where exactly it failed? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I can't directly post the full traceback because s.o. says its spam but I posted it on this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/DrsvsuVr

Comment: Oh, it failed during fitting. Well, I think the most appropriate way to approach debugging this is to print out shapes of the vectors in createModel and try to find a problematic layer where the problem is introduced.

Comment: Did you figure this out?